# Wordpress hosting good practice

Tags: hosting, shared-hosting, hosting-recommendation

Hello Wordpress developers, I need advice from you.

I need to host Wordpress site for a client and I decided to use recommended hosting providers like Blue Host, Site Ground and Namecheap.

So what is recommended practice? Should a client register his account and buy hosting service with his own credit card and provide hosting/server/database access to me or I should register my personal account and pay hosting service with my card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems off-topic, but I'll answer anyway.

It entirely depends on your arrangement with the client, as well as whether you want to take care of supporting your client's site after you deliver it to them.

Reputable hosts like wpengine.com provide different levels of access via developer roles: your client pays for everything and has access to everything, then invites you to their account and you have access to all the technical and support tickets functionality needed to do your work (but not the invoicing).

P.S.: Not affiliated with Wpengine, I just know for a fact they provide what I described above.